# How to create div cards in html dynamically using javascript & jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created this card for design purpose but i want to create html card dynamically using JavaScript or jQuery, means if I pass 5 value in a loop then 5 cards create with same design. How can I do this?

```html
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <img id="card-shopping-cart-icon" src="images/cart.png" alt="">
    <img id="card-wishlist-icon" src="images/heart.png" alt="">
    <img id="card-image" src="images/motorola_one.jpg" alt="Motorola" class="contain">

    <div class="card-text-body">
      <p class="card-clock-deals-title">Motorola One Power</p>
      <p class="card-clock-deals-detail">RAM 4/6GB ROM 64GB</p>
      <p class="card-clock-deals-discounted-price">2000</p>
      <p>
        <table class="card-clock-deals-timer">
          <tr>
            <td id="hours">12</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td id="minutes">00</td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </p>
      <p class="card-clock-deals-original-price">3000</p>
      <p class="card-clock-deals-timer-text">Hrs Left</p>
      <p class="card-clock-deals-like-image"><img src="images/heart.png" alt="">(381)</p>
    </div </div>
```

I created this card for design purpose but i want to create html card dynamically using JavaScript or jQuery, means if I pass 5 value in a loop then 5 cards create with same design. How can I do this?

Comment: You should store the info of the 5 cards somewhere, in a database or in a file, then read the info and make a loop with PHP or JS depending where you stored your info.

Comment: Exactly, I have a database where information is already saved but I want to create dynamic cards? How do I create because in above code i have multiple div. I couldn't fix?

Comment: So you should create the connection file to the database and then get the info from the table to create the dynamic cards depending on the records on the database, if you could paste more code will be so useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I asked you, you're using a database to store the data from the cards right? So all you need is create the connection to the database, then fetch the result with a loop to display one by one the cards.

```
        // Here you need to create your connection to the database with your values
        <?php
            include 'connection.php';
        //Here write your SQL query to get the data from your cards database
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM cards";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
        ?>

        // Then we start with the html code to get the data and show the cards
        <!doctype html>
        <html>
          <body>
           <h1 align="center">CARDS</h1>
        <?php
        //Fetch Data form database
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
         ?>
            <div class="scrolling-wrapper">
            <div class="card">

            <img id="card-shopping-cart-icon" src="images/cart.png" alt="">
            <img id="card-wishlist-icon" src="images/heart.png" alt="">
            <img id="card-image" src="images/<?php echo $row['RowNameYouWannaGet']; ?>" alt="Motorola" class="contain">

        <div class="card-text-body">
              <p class="card-clock-deals-title"><?php echo $row['RowNameYouWannaGet']; ?></p>
              <p class="card-clock-deals-detail"><?php echo $row['RowNameYouWannaGet']; ?></p>
              <p class="card-clock-deals-discounted-price"><?php echo $row['RowNameYouWannaGet']; ?></p>
              <p>
                <table class="card-clock-deals-timer">
                  <tr>
                    <td id="hours"><?php echo $row['RowNameYouWannaGet']; ?></td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td id="minutes"><?php echo $row['RowNameYouWannaGet']; ?></td>
                  </tr>

                </table>
              </p>
              <p class="card-clock-deals-original-price"><?php echo $row['RowNameYouWannaGet']; ?></p>
              <p class="card-clock-deals-timer-text"><?php echo $row['RowNameYouWannaGet']; ?></p>
              <p class="card-clock-deals-like-image"><img src="images/heart.png" alt=""><?php echo $row['RowNameYouWannaGet']; ?></p>
          </div>
       </div>
         <?php
           }
           }
           else
            { echo "No data found" } ?>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Hope it helps, you can also find info on Google searching--> Dynamic Tables PHP, MySQL

Answer (score 1):

**ONLY FOR BOOTSTRAP 4 and above HTML CODE BELOW AND FIND "JAVASCRIPT FOR CARDS"*

```
    <div class="container row col-12 col-sm-12 justify-content-center" id="parsi">
    <div class="card" style="width:18 rem;">
        <img  class="card-img-top"src="#" alt="">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h1>This is an card</h1>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing 
            elit. Tempore, repudiandae neque? Placeat harum veniam omnis dolorum 
            necessitatibus vitae, nisi ducimus illum.</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
             onclick="myclick()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**"JAVASCRIPT FOR CARDS" ==>**

```
function myclick(){
    var x= prompt("Enter number of cards u want to make","6");
    if (x!=null){
        var main=document.getElementById("parsi");
        let num=parseInt(x);
        var i;
        const red="Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, 
        repudiandae neque? Placeat harum veniam omnis dolorum necessitatibus vitae, 
        nisi ducimus illum.";
        var div=[];
        for (i=0;i<num;i++){
            div.push(document.createElement("div"));
            div[i].setAttribute("class","card col-12 col-sm-3 ml-2 mt-3");
            div[i].setAttribute("style","width:18 rem;");
            const image=document.createElement("img");
            image.setAttribute("class","card-img-top");
            image.src="#";
            div[i].appendChild(image);
            var innerDiv=document.createElement("div");
            innerDiv.setAttribute("class","card-body");
            var h1=document.createElement("h1");
            h1.textContent="This is the heading";
            var p1=document.createElement("p1");
            p1.setAttribute("class","card-text");
            p1.textContent=red;
            innerDiv.appendChild(h1);
            innerDiv.appendChild(p1);
            div[i].appendChild(innerDiv);
            main.appendChild(div[i]);

        }
        


    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have created jsFiddle demo for this.

https://jsfiddle.net/wer4px80/2/

html:

```
<div id="scrolling-wrapper"></div>
```

javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  var count = 5;

  var html = "";
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++)
  {
    html += "<div class='card'>card " + i +"</div>";
    html += "<br>";
  }
  $("#scrolling-wrapper").html(html);

});
```

Please check if you need to generate more cards you can change the variable value and change html content as per your needs.

You should get dynamic data using ajax from your endpoint which provides you the data stored somewhere in your database you need to render on your page.

Also you can look into handlebars or mustache templating tools for better handling of dynamic content.

Links are given below:

https://mustache.github.io/

https://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: You're just setting the html value of an element to contain 5 divs.  You've not taken anything in the question into account.